# Can p4 ignore a change list in the history?

Tags: perforce

In my p4 i have this setup:

```
//depot/base/... //work/...
+//depot/customization/... //work/...
```

The base layer contain all the source code, and customization only contain files that need to modify which will override the base layer (like home.php in customization will replace home.php in base).

Now let's say I realize i want use the original file i don't need to use the home.php in customization layer,  so I mark for delete for that file, then if i sync the workspace, on my local i will be missing that home.php since customization layer has that delete action in the history.

I could add one more line in p4 like this:

```
+//depot/base/home.php //work/home.php
```

But what happen if you have multiple files, is there a way that make this changelist not stored into p4 history?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to completely remove that file (or any of its revisions) from the history is via the "p4 obliterate" command.